# Structural Diff of two java source files

Tags: diff, java

Is there any way to find Structural diff of two java source files? 
I want to find structural difference of two java files, but i don't know how to start it. 
Is there any library in java for this purpose?

Update:
Structural diff means like 
it does not care about white space or locations. It should compares source a syntactically. This helps us to trace actual changes, even if methods are moved to another location or appear in different order.

i found a tool that is for C# and pascal but i need it for java source file comparision. please check the given link
http://www.modelmakertools.com/structured-diff-viewer/index.html

if you know any libraries for that purpose please share it.
thank you

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "structural diff"?

Comment: Elaborate `Structural Difference`?

Comment: user file comparison tool

Comment: See http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/SmartDifferencer/JavaSmartDifferencer.html

Answer (score 4):

Eclipse JDT has a structural compare of java sources. If you have special requirements than it might be a good idea to have a look at [Eclipse EMF](http://www.eclipse.org/modeling/emf/?project=emf) and especially [EMF Compare](http://www.eclipse.org/emf/compare/). For a starting point for using Eclipse Modeling you might also want to have a look at [Eclipse MoDisco](http://www.eclipse.org/MoDisco/). It ships with a Java 5 EMF Model and therefore also provides structural diff with EMF Compare.